# How can I use html form with aframe.js?

Tags: javascript, aframe

I am creating a 3d web page for laptop use only.

How should I enable text input and use HTML form  library in HTML?

I have found various API to print text on 3d web page but no any related to HTML form. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

WebGL is a different environment from the 2D Web. It is non-trivial to pull in normal HTML forms and enable text input. In WebGL, forms, UI, and input have to be built from the ground up until someone creates a nice library or component for it. It also depends on what devices are available.

I don't know how far you'd get with DOM-to-canvas-to-texture implementations like https://github.com/mayognaise/aframe-html-shader , that might be good place to look at.

Or to build from the ground up:

- Represent your form through meshes (planes and boxes) and text.
- Listen to keyboard events to append and modify text from your form.
- Create a button through a mesh and listen for user input to submit the form.